# Codeigniter - Mail sent using MAIL protocol but not received - debugger shows no error

Tags: codeigniter, email, debugging

```
Array ( [useragent] => Stock Manager Advance [protocol] => mail [mailtype] => html [crlf] => [newline] => )
```

This is the `$config` parameters passing to the Email library to **Initialize**.

While sending email it returns **true** but mail not received. I've tried SMTP and Send Mail too but its not working anymore.

When I've tried to debug email for any errors it was just print as `<pre></pre>`.

Is there any possibilities to find the error? or anything like server error.
Need solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: In your send function put this $this->email->send(false); then use the debugger $this->email->print_debugger(); and post the result for more information.

Comment: https://ibb.co/kfE1h9 Kindly check this image

Comment: The log shows that the mail was sent, but my guess is that your server is detecting it as spam. You might want to consider not using the mail() function and instead using SMTP to send your mail. That way the email message will be authenticated.